# XOR problem with bipolar representation

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, backpropagation

I am taking a course in Machine Learning and the Professor introduced us to the XOR problem.

I understand the XOR problem is not linearly separable and we need to employ Neural Network for this problem.

However, he mentioned XOR works better with Bipolar representation(-1, +1) which I have not really understand.

I am wondering what Bipolar representation would be better than Binary Representation? Whats the rationale for saying so?

Comment: If bipolar means values +1 and -1 only, this scheme is totally equivalent to {0, +1}, being the mapping (x+1)/2. The NN can handle both, even doing the mapping at a first layer with bias. Some activation functions could be more valid in one case or another thinking in learning performance.

Comment: xor is not separable with a single hyperplane, but it is with two. There are lots of methods different to NN able to handle this subject.

Comment: But why Bipolar representation works better for this problem?